# Looking to find the name and objective of this puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, puzzle-identification

I'm playing an escape room game that requires me to play this game. It's my first time coming across this type of puzzle so I'm confused as to what I am suppose to do with it.  If anyone can tell me the name, or any site that can show a tutorial about it, I would be grateful,  thank you. 
[image: puzzle]

Answer (score 15):

Looks very similar to [Simon Tatham's "Net"](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/net.html). The goal is to get everything connected together; the operation you're allowed to do is to rotate each square by any multiple of 90 degrees.

Comment: There's also "Netslide", where you slide any row or column left/right/up/down and the overflowing piece gets put to the other end.